# Is there a bug in WebKit/Blink's implementation of flexbox's flex-flow: column wrap?

Tags: webkit, flexbox, gecko, blink

Is this a bug in WebKit/Blink?

I'm trying to implement an article summary page similar to that of a newspaper: article summaries flow down and 'wrap' from left to right, exactly as specified in the `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` sections of [the W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-direction-property). The remaining space in a column should be redistributed evenly between the blocks that occupy it (just like `flex-grow: 1`).

See **[the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2kcLh9n/)**.

Firefox appears to have implemented this correctly, but I get a very strange layout from Chrome and Safari.

If this is indeed a bug, is there a workaround?

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome/Safari:

[image: Chrome/Safari]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `max-height: 24rem` to `height: 24rem;` then it works in Chrome.

It looks like Chrome is calculating the height based on the smallest block.

```css
body {
  background: #C6C2B6;
}

section {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 24rem;
}

article {
  background: #48929B;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-height: 10rem;
  width: 4rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.big {
  min-height: 14rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article class="big"></article>
  <article></article>
</section>
```

Comment: I know this wasn't in the original question, but what about http://jsfiddle.net/4cq6z2j2/ ? If the height should be determined by the content, then what? Firefox still renders correctly while WebKit fails.

Comment: I replaced my answer with this fiddle and I think this gets what you want. Here is the link, too: http://jsfiddle.net/4cq6z2j2/4/

Comment: Nevermind, my new answer is basically the same as the original answer.

Comment: It did still answer my question, so thank you! I'll submit a new question and maybe file a bug when I've done some more exploration.